# Please let me know why I can not install RedMine connector

Tags: eclipse, installation, redmine, mylyn

If you install from Eclipse, it will continue to fail.
I am using jdk1.8.0 and Eclipse Neon.3.
Please let me know why I can not install RedMine connector

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Mylyn Connector: Redmine 0.4.0.201602071631 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.4.0.201602071631)
  Missing requirement: Mylyn Connector: Redmine 0.4.0.201602071631 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.4.0.201602071631) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.log 1.2.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
The solution to this problem is
Kepler in org.eclipse.equinox.log bundle was uninstalled error.

```
To fix this, go to Help> install software> add> 
Update url: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 >
Equinox Target Components - Equinox Target Components
```

I hope it helps someone else.